# Connecting a TCP client to my server from external IP

Tags: python, networking, tcp, server

I have made a simple TCP server and client in Python. Everything works fine when I use the local IP of the server, but not with the public IP. My server has a static IP and is bound to this IP and a port, and the client is trying to connect to the public IP with the same port. I've set up port forwarding on my router to supposedly redirect traffic to that port to the server's local IP. The router is a Netgear X4S R7800.

Neither the server nor the client crash at any point. The client just times out eventually and throws an exception, and the server doesn't seem to receive any connection at all.

**Server.py**

```
from socket import *
SERVER_NAME = '192.168.1.140' #My server's (static) local IP
SERVER_PORT = 12100

def initializeServer():
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind((SERVER_NAME, SERVER_PORT))
    serverSocket.listen(5)
    print("Server initialized to port " + str(SERVER_PORT) +"...")
    return serverSocket

def serverLoop(serverSocket):
    while True:
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() #Gets stuck here
        print("Connected to", addr)
        listenToClient(connectionSocket)
        print("Terminating client connection ...")
        connectionSocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverSocket = initializeServer()
    try:
        serverLoop(serverSocket)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        shutdownServer(serverSocket)
        print("\nServer shut down")
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket
SERVER_NAME = '193.91.XXX.XXX'  #Public IP
SERVER_PORT = 12100

def connectToServer(serverName, serverPort):
    clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort)) #Gets stuck here and eventually times out
    return clientSocket

def main():
    try:
        serverSocket = connectToServer(SERVER_NAME, SERVER_PORT)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Cannot connect to the server\n", e)
    else:
        print("Connected to server")
        try:
            askForUserAction(serverSocket)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            serverSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As you say the code works locally, it’s obviously a networking problem - port forwarding, firewall, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved it. My modem provided by my ISP is apparently also a router. I have another router and I was connected to and forwarding ports from this one. Just had to change the setting of my ISP's router and it worked fine.